# JavaScript equivalent to JQuery AJAX petition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want is to return a request that I made in JQuery, to JavaScript. The youmightnotneedjquery code has not worked for me, I want to be able to do exactly the same as I do with my JQuery request, but with JavaScript.

JQuery code:

```
function leer(user){
    
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "API/clientes.php",
        Type: "json",
        data: { usuario: user}
    }).done(function( data ) {
        var objeto= $.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(objeto,function( index, element ) {
            var body = $('table tbody');
            body.append(
                "<tr>"+
                    "<td>"+element.nombre+'</td>'+
                "</tr>"
            );
        })
    })
```

PHP code:

```
<?php require_once('conexion.php'); ?>
 <?php   
    if(isset($_GET["usuario"]) && $_GET['usuario'] == "soyReynald"){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        $arreglo = array();

        while( $mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
            array_push($arreglo, $mostrar);
        }
        echo( json_encode($arreglo) );
    }
?>
<?php require_once('desconectar.php'); ?>
```

What I am looking to do with JavaScript is to request a PHP file through AJAX and consume it as an API, I tried to do it with the following code but it did not work for me...

What I have tried:

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'API/clientes.php', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    var data = {usuario: user}
    
    request.onload = function() {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
        // Success!
        var obj = JSON.parse(this.response);
        obj.forEach(element => {
            var body = document.querySelector('table tbody');
            body.append(
                "<tr>"+
                    "<td>"+element.nombre+'</td>'+
                "</tr>"
            );
        });
        } else {
            alert("An error");
    
        }
    };

    request.send(data);
```

Thanks and blessings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced your code with using fetch instead of `XMLHttpRequest`. I also updated the append loop to create the TR as an element then append that as a child of the table.

You will want to change the URL and `element.body` to `element.nombre`

```js
the_url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"    
params = { usuario: user};

var url = new URL(the_url)

url.search = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();

fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {

    data.forEach(element => {
      var body = document.querySelector('table tbody');
      tr = document.createElement("tr");
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = element.body;
      tr.appendChild(td);
      body.appendChild(tr);
    });

  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    // There was an error
    console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
  });
```

```html
<table>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```